# My button style in Xamarin is not applying to my button leaving it blank

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

So I have this issue where I'm trying to create buttons for a login form. But for some reason when i use (android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignUpStyle") It just leaves the button blank.

This is my Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:weightSum="100"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:text="Sign Up Now"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#368BDE"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/txtSignUp" />
<Button
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignInStyle"
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Or"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/txtOr" />
<Button
    android:text="Sign Up With E-mail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignUpStyle" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ProgressBarStyle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my button style for one of the button @drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http//:schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="false">

<layer-list>
  <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
      <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:left="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
      <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#4A6EA9" android:startColor="#4A6EA9"/>
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
      <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
</item>



<item android:state_pressed="true">

<layer-list>
  <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
      <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:left="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
      <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#7C97C1" android:startColor="#4A6EA9"/>
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
      <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

and my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="LoginSystem.LoginSystem" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<application android:label="LoginSystem"></application>
</manifest>
```

I Did my best to find answers myself but I failed. I am very new to coding so might be something really basic.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a very tiny mistake in your style:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http//:schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Change the url to:

http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

then your style works by my side:

[image]

Comment: @GustavEiman, If you find this answer helpful, could you plese [mark this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? Thx.

Comment: Done, my bad! New to the site!